# How to calculate 32 bit CRC in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, crc, crc32

I want to calculate 32 bit CRC value for 'input field value"  in Ruby on rails.
need the sample code , please help me anyone.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use Ruby's Zlib module.

```
require 'zlib'
crc32 = Zlib::crc32('input field value')
```